Perform spearman test with cor.test on different sized dataframe
I am trying to perform a cor.test (spearman) on a set of data. I am following the workflow of this article (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41564-023-01350-w) in order to evaluate and discriminate contaminants in a set of data I have. The previous passage required are to caluclate the prevalence and filter out those data that do not reach a specific treshold. After this passage i obtain a set of data that are classified as contaminants (those below the treshold) and a set of potential contaminants (above the treshold).
The step i'm stuck at is the following:
A microbial species is considered a contami-
nant if it is highly correlated (Spearman’s ρ > 0.7) with any con-
taminant within the same batch, as identified by the prevalence
filter. This filter is based on the principle that contaminants are
highly correlated within the same batch. Spearman’s ρ was
calculated using centred log-ratio-transformed77 microbial
relative abundances. Centred log-ratio transformations and
Spearman’s ρ were calculated using the clr function of the com-
positions package78 and cor.test function in R.
I know i cannot perform the cor.test on dataset of different dimension but i don't see how i can calculate the spearman p. The 2 dataframe i have are FilPv1[281x11] and FilPV1NONCont[1743x11]. The column i have to apply the cor.test is called Prev.
Thank you kindly in advance
I tried to do a nested for loop by trying to loop every value of the non contaminants with the contaminants but get the error that i do not have enough observation

for (i in 1:nrow(FilPv1)){
  for (x in 1:nrow(FilPV1NONCont))
  cor.test(FilPv1$Prev[i], FilPV1NONCont$Prev[x], method = "spearman")
}

I know that in this way i get 1 value against another one, but how should i approach this problem?
The 2 data frame have the following structure:
> head(FilPV1NONCont)
        Prev     totAb  Kingdom         Phylum              Class           Order           Family        Genus
101571     1 0.8581138 Bacteria Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria Burkholderiales Burkholderiaceae Burkholderia
1503054    1 0.3168894 Bacteria Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria Burkholderiales Burkholderiaceae Burkholderia
87883      1 0.2786909 Bacteria Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria Burkholderiales Burkholderiaceae Burkholderia
60550      1 0.1883047 Bacteria Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria Burkholderiales Burkholderiaceae Burkholderia
152480     1 0.3580607 Bacteria Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria Burkholderiales Burkholderiaceae Burkholderia
488447     1 0.1884915 Bacteria Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria Burkholderiales Burkholderiaceae Burkholderia
            Species      clr cont
101571    ubonensis 7.404605    0
1503054   stagnalis 6.408421    0
87883   multivorans 6.279972    0
60550    pyrrocinia 5.887930    0
152480    ambifaria 6.530571    0
488447  contaminans 5.888922    0

> head(FilPv1)

             Prev        totAb  Kingdom         Phylum              Class           Order           Family
1636423 0.3636364 0.0040465871 Bacteria Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria Burkholderiales Burkholderiaceae
1478019 0.3636364 0.0028885249 Bacteria Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria Burkholderiales Burkholderiaceae
96344   0.7272727 0.0047268082 Bacteria Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria Burkholderiales Burkholderiaceae
82541   0.3636364 0.0014331855 Bacteria Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria Burkholderiales Burkholderiaceae
1855616 0.4545455 0.0008442892 Bacteria Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria Burkholderiales Burkholderiaceae
2878150 0.6363636 0.0072747175 Bacteria Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria Burkholderiales Burkholderiaceae
                   Genus       Species        clr cont
1636423     Burkholderia  sp. MSMB1588  0.1411178    1
1478019      Cupriavidus      sp. KK10 -0.1960100    1
96344        Cupriavidus    oxalaticus  0.2964942    1
82541        Cupriavidus      gilardii -0.8968564    1
1855616 Polynucleobacter sp. MWH-UH25E -1.4260161    1
2878150     Caballeronia    sp. Lep1P3  0.7276490    1


Can you provide an example? Specifically for FilPv1 and FilPV1NONCont? For example, you can paste the output in your post: dput(FilPV1NONCont).

yes sure, I updated the post with a head of the two dataframe. I wasn't able to post the dput since the output was too big.

How do you define batch number? Is it everything within the data frames you provided, or is a batch number one line (indicated by the rowname)?
